# Dual boot with separate drives. GRUB in the wrong EPS

Tags: dual-boot

Have an issue with dual boot (Ubuntu 20.04 / Windows 10).

I installed Windows 10 first, and just incase, I unplugged the other drive so Windows can't put any files on it.

I then replugged the other drive without unplugging anything else just so the GRUB could find the Windows entry during the installation of Ubuntu. For the partitioning, I chose `Something Else`, and created a 600MB EFI partition, a 20GB swap partition and the rest was left for the `/`.

After the partitioning, it looks like that:

```
sdb      8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   100M  0 part <--- Windows EFI / GRUB goes here for some reason
├─sdb2   8:18   0    16M  0 part 
├─sdb3   8:19   0 465.1G  0 part 
└─sdb4   8:20   0   519M  0 part 
sdc      8:32   0 223.6G  0 disk 
├─sdc1   8:33   0   571M  0 part <--- I want GRUB here
├─sdc2   8:34   0  18.6G  0 part 
└─sdc3   8:35   0 204.4G  0 part
```

`sdb` is the drive where Windows 10 is installed, where as `sdc` is the one with Ubuntu. I carefully chose the `sdc1` partition (EFI) for the GRUB installation during the partitioning, however it ended up in sdb1 which is the EFI partition for Windows.

FYI, both disks are partitioned with `GPT`, both are UEFI based installations.

I solved the issue by just unplugging the Windows SSD during Ubuntu installation, however I still want to know why Ubuntu just completely bypasses the device I chose for the GRUB? And just installs itself in the first EFI partition it sees which is the Windows one.

Comment: Did you specify the correct mountpoint for the desired ESP (`/boo/efi`) in your first attempt ( while the windows drive was connected)?

Comment: @mook765 Yes. When I created `sdc1`, I chose EFI for the type and selected it as target for GRUB.

Comment: This seems to be an old but still unresolved bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379

Comment: @SiepKroonenberg Oh well, I guess I'll just unplug the other drive if I need to reinstall either operating system. Thanks for the information.